# Is there a Gtk 3 version of Audacity?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, audacity

I am using Audacity to edit simple sound files (crop, noise reduction, etc) and I consider it to be perfect for small tasks like these. However, after I installed it from the Snap Store, I found it to have an old-style Gtk-2 look and feel.

[image]

When I change the theme to Dark (`Edit -> Preferences -> Interface -> Theme -> Dark`), some elements did not change the color, specially the drop-down menus and the time labels at the bottom.

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to change the user interface theme to use something more similar to Gtk 3, which would look awesome and would also be more coherent with Gnome 3 interface.

If that is not possible, is there a way to change the color of these elements on Audacity whose colors were not affected by theming?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=audacity

Comment: So you mean I should install de deb version instead of the snap?

Comment: It's offered as an option that I believe will resolve the issue... If you grabbed the *snap* to get specific versions it may not be ideal, in which case hopefully you'll get other choices from others...

Comment: I installed the deb version and it looks great now. I just wonder why this is happening to snap applications. Recently I had the same issue with Inkscape and it was fixed by uninstalling the snap version and later installing the deb version. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Snaps run in a confined environment with limited access to your real file system ; classically confinement snaps can read more of your actual visual settings, where as standard snaps have almost no access, thus do not know your settings/theme. It's for security reasons, however it means that snapped programs may not match your chosen visual themes where changed from default, as get a 'phony' view of your actual file system.  The issue is being worked on...